# document.querySelector abstraction

Tags: javascript, dom

I always found a pain to write `let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');`

So I was playing with javascript and thought about doing writing a function for a sugar syntax, I came up with:

```
function dq(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

let h1 = dq('h1');

h1.onclick = () => {
  console.log('yey');
};
```

So, my question is: are there any downsides of doing that in my code?

Comment: No.  However, it's "fancier" to bind click event using addEventListener.

Comment: I thing that if there is any downside regarding this approach is the that the readers of your code would have to interpret what does the function `dq` and see that actually is a wrapper of `document.querySelector`, which is one of the most well known methods. Furthermore you make one more call to a function, which actually does nothing, but you have one more call.

Comment: `let btn = document.querySelector('btn');` no error? There are no `<btn>` tags lastime I checked.

Comment: Even though it makes the code more easily to write, it makes it harder to other people read.

Answer (score 0):

What are you essentially doing is what code minifiers do, just manually - obfuscating the code a little bit.

Your code is shorter, but harder to read. Also, it really only works for `document.querySelector`, not for example for `document.body.querySelector` or any other element's `querySelector` method.

Instead, create a code snippet/template in your preferred IDE. Code snippets are designed to do exactly what you want: less writing.

Comment: I think that I haven't understood yet that I don't write code only for myself. Thanks!

Comment: @EmersonLopes That's one more reason to stay away from non-standard code expressions that will only confuse your colleagues.